# gSoap Exchange Web Services Connection

Tags: c++, exchangewebservices, gsoap

I'm trying to write an application that would work with the EWS proxy classes. To generate proxy classes I used gsoap (compiled OpenSSL).
I have implemented a library that works with EWS, but. Net.
The problem is this: I have no idea how to implement a connection to the server.
Doing the following:

```
ExchangeServiceBindingProxy *proxy = new ExchangeServiceBindingProxy("https://192.168.0.49/EWS/exchange.asmx");
soap *pSoap = proxy->soap;
pSoap->userid = "user1";
pSoap->passwd = "password1";
pSoap->recv_timeout = 300;
pSoap->send_timeout = 300;

SOAP_ENV__Header *header = new SOAP_ENV__Header();
header->ns3__RequestServerVersion = new _ns3__RequestServerVersion();
header->ns3__RequestServerVersion->soap = pSoap;
header->ns3__RequestServerVersion->Version = ns3__ExchangeVersionType__Exchange2010;
pSoap->header = header;

//get root folder ID
ns3__DistinguishedFolderIdType *dfit = new ns3__DistinguishedFolderIdType();
dfit->Id = ns3__DistinguishedFolderIdNameType__inbox;

//set the props that we want to retrieve
ns3__FolderResponseShapeType *frst = new ns3__FolderResponseShapeType();
frst->BaseShape = ns3__DefaultShapeNamesType__AllProperties;

//get folder
ns1__GetFolderType *gftRoot = new ns1__GetFolderType();
gftRoot->FolderIds = new ns3__NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
gftRoot->FolderIds->__union_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType = new __ns3__union_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
gftRoot->FolderIds->__union_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType->union_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType.DistinguishedFolderId = dfit;
gftRoot->FolderShape = frst;
__ns1__GetFolderResponse response;


int error = proxy->GetFolder(gftRoot, response);
```

As a result, getting the error: SLL_ERROR.

I know, that i`m doing something wrong. But what? What i should to do, to use proxy classes functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by myself:
Added to project LibNTLM and added to preprocessor WITH_NTLM.

Also changed code, a little bit:

```
ExchangeServiceBindingProxy *proxy = new ExchangeServiceBindingProxy(endpoint.c_str());

soap *pSoap = proxy->soap;
pSoap->userid = "Ivan1";
pSoap->passwd = "1";
pSoap->ntlm_challenge = "";
pSoap->authrealm = "Ursa-Minor";

pSoap->ssl_flags = SOAP_SSL_NO_AUTHENTICATION;
//pSoap->keep_alive = true; 
pSoap->mode = SOAP_IO_KEEPALIVE;

//get root folder ID
ns3__DistinguishedFolderIdType *dfit = new ns3__DistinguishedFolderIdType();
dfit->Id = ns3__DistinguishedFolderIdNameType__inbox;

//set the props that we want to retrieve
ns3__FolderResponseShapeType *frst = new ns3__FolderResponseShapeType();
frst->BaseShape = ns3__DefaultShapeNamesType__AllProperties;

//get folder
ns1__GetFolderType *gftRoot = new ns1__GetFolderType();
gftRoot->FolderIds = new ns3__NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
gftRoot->FolderIds->__size_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType = 1;
gftRoot->FolderIds->__union_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType = new __ns3__union_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
gftRoot->FolderIds->__union_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType->union_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType.DistinguishedFolderId = dfit;
gftRoot->FolderIds = (ns3__NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType*)dfit;
gftRoot->FolderShape = frst;
__ns1__GetFolderResponse response;

int qq = proxy->GetFolder(gftRoot, response);

return true;
```

But now i have enother problems: [Error 500: Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562854/gsoap-ews-error-500-internal-server-error)